# Combine 2 Boolean statements to make another one

Tags: java, boolean, boolean-expression

I am trying to combine two boolean statements in order to validate a number.

This is the code for the two functions:

```
public boolean numberOne(String number)
{
    int a = Integer.parseInt(number);
    if(a >= 0 && a <= 7 && number.length() <= 1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}


public boolean numberTwo(String number)
{
    int b = Integer.parseInt(number);
    if(b >= 01 && b <= 15 && number.length() <= 2) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now I want to create another Boolean function to validate this number when both combined e.g. 215 would be true and 645 would be false.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: How would `numberOne("215")` return `true` when you're testing `number.length() <= 1`?

Comment: Well I want to add both the boolen functions. So the first function would be 2 which is true. And the second would allow 15. So that is also true when both combined it should make a 3 figure number.

Comment: Second remark: you have a variable 'x' in the second function.  This would give a compilation error.

Answer (score 3):

Two changes.  The first is a side note.  This code

```
if (long_test) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

should be rewritten as this:

```
return long_test;
```

The other change described by dampee once he gets his variable names to match.

Answer (score 2):

Ok.  So you want to split the string and have the first number of the string compared to the first function and the last two numbers compared to the second function?

```
public boolean numberThree (String number) {
    String part1 = number.substring(0, 1);
    String part2 = number.substring(1);
    return numberOne(part1) && numberTwo(part2);
}
```

Comment: Hmm isnt var JavaScript? Plus I want it as a Boolean function.

Comment: I get a syntax error with the numbers of O, 1 when converting to a String

Comment: Ah!  of cource, you need to replace str by "number"  :-)

Comment: Yep.  There is also an issue with the functions themselves (see below)